# Javascript replace function reg exp with apex

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm using javascript replace function, but it doesn't seem to work with the apex:

```
myText = "This is an apex ' and this is another apex ' ";
myText.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/,''));
```

This should skip the apex ('), but it doesn't!!

http://jsfiddle.net/GMBMt/5/

Any idea how to resolve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written this will only replace a single occurrence, add a `g` (global) modifier:

```
myText.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g, ''));
```

This will result in:

```
Thisisanapexandthisisanotherapex
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/GMBMt/6/) is an updated fiddle.